# Which MLB team had the shortest "longest winning streak" in a pennant-winning season?

Tags: trivia, mlb

Which team won the pennant but never won more than X games in a row, with X being the lowest number?

For example, the hypothetical team the Rainbow Sox won the pennant in 1717, but never won more than 3 games in a row during that pennant winning season, and no team had a lower number, then the answer would be the "Rainbow Sox in 1717, longest streak of 3".

Answer (score 1):

There are three teams in MLB history who have won the [National League pennant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_National_League_pennant_winners) but never won more than 5 games in a row during their winning season. 
The [2010 San Francisco Giants](https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/SFG/2010-schedule-scores.shtml), [2011 St. Louis Cardinals](https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/STL/2011-schedule-scores.shtml) and [2018 Los Angeles Dodgers](https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/LAD/2018-schedule-scores.shtml) all won the pennant with their longest winning streak being 5 games.