# Which NBA team had the shortest "longest winning streak" in a championship-winning season?

Tags: basketball, statistics, history, nba

Inspired by this question: [Which MLB team had the shortest "longest winning streak" in a pennant-winning season?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/21284)

Which NBA team had the shortest "longest winning streak" during a championship-winning season? In other words, which team won the championship but never won more than X games in a row, with X being the lowest number, during that season?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three teams in NBA history who have won the [NBA championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NBA_champions) but never won more than 5 games in a row during their winning season. The [**1947 Philadelphia Warriors**](https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/PHW/1947_games.html), [**1969 Boston Celtics**](https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/BOS/1969_games.html) and [**1978 Washington Bullets**](https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/WSB/1978_games.html) all won the championship with their longest season winning streak being 5 games.

Comment: I went through the worst records to win the NBA championship, and came across the same findings. Though it is theoretically possible for a 50+ win team to have less consecutive wins than 5, I'm going to defer to your answer, especially if you looked at all championship teams.